# Blazor WASM PWA Could not find any element matching selector 'app'

Tags: progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I am using Visual Studio 2019 v16.8.5 and have a single Blazor WASM PWA project in my solution that I recently upgraded to .NET5. In between I got it to run, but lately I cannot get to start it anymore.

The screen says *Loading...* and that's it.
The console output (Firefox) shows the following error: `Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find any element matching selector 'app'.`
At some point this was running without this issue, but even reverting the solution to an earlier state does not bring any change and I still get a blank screen.

I found a github source saying "just remove `builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");` from `Program` `Main`". If I do this, the error disappears and I just get a blank page saying *Loading...* with no errors in Console output.

Additional information: I now do a full cache cleanup (cookies and website files) after running the project in Visual Studio to prevent any caching issues.

What am I doing wrong that I can't see any of my pages?
Even after explicitely calling them like `https://192.168.188.31:5555/login`?

Comment: Go to your index.html. Depending on the template version used to create the initial app, a slightly different HTML is used for the app. Older version could like like: ```  <app>Loading...</app>``` newer should like ```<div id="app">Loading...</div>```.  For  the first it is ```builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");``` And for the second builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app"); The second has the id selector ```#```.

Comment: Oh wow, going back and forth with all the changes, this must have been stuck in cache when I tried it before. Thank you very much, the `#` did the trick for me. Do you want to add as an answer, so I can mark it as a solution.

Comment: I'm glad that you found your solution. During development, the cache is a curse and blessing at the same time. :)

I've posted the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depending on the template version used to create the initial app, a slightly different HTML is used inside the `index.html`.

Older version could look like

`<app>Loading...</app>`

while newer should like

`<div id="app">Loading...</div>`

In case, the first is still true, the corresponding declaration should be

`builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");`

For the second the line should be

`builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");`

The second uses the id selector `#`.

Usually, the `index.html` is seen as a "static" file and is cached by the browser. So changes, you have done in that file are not reflected immediately. The easiest way to disable the cache is to open the developer tools, go to the Network tab and disable the cache.

[image: disabling the network cache in the network tab of the developer tools.]

Comment: Thanks! Indeed the index.html will be cached in the browser.
So reload the page using Ctrl + F5 (Chrome) will also resolve this issue.